# Use subquery in linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

How can I construct the below sql query in linq query to get the results ?

```
SELECT PageNumber from LMS_SurveyQuestion WHERE SurveyQuestionID IN
(SELECT  SurveyQuestionID from LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice 
WHERE NextPageNumber = 4) and SurveyID = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://rob.conery.io/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/). Basically, if you want to implement SQL IN query in LINQ, you need to construct an inner query first, and then use the Contains() method. Here's my attempt:

```
var innerQuery = (from log in LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice where log.NextPageNumber = 4 select log.SurveyQuestionID);

var result = (from f in LMS_SurveyQuestion where innerQuery.Contains(f.SurveyQuestionID) && f.SurveyID = 1 select f);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: But where is SurveyID = 1 is used ? SurveyID  belongs to LMS_SurveyQuestion.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var result = from l in LMS_SurveyQuestion 
             let lsq = from l_S in LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice 
             where l_S.NextPageNumber = 4
             select l_S.SurveyQuestionID 
             where lsq.Contains(l.SurveyQuestionID) and l.surveyid = 1
             select l.PageNumber;
```

Comment: But where is SurveyID = 1 is used ? SurveyID  belongs to LMS_SurveyQuestion.